# Singular homology of a quotient of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ by an order $2$ action.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $\mathbb{C}P^n$ be complex projective $n$-space. Let $f:\mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$ be the map given by $[x_0,\dots,x_n]\rightarrow [-x_0,\dots,x_n]$.

Let $X:=\mathbb{C}P^n/\{1,f\}$ be the orbit space by this action. I would like to complete the singular homology groups of $X$. My conjecture is this: $H_i(X)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ iff $i\leq n$ and $i$ is even and it is zero otherwise.

I have attempted the following methods to do so. The second method appears to have a higher chance of success.

First, I tried Mayer-Vietoris by looking at the quotients $S^{2n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow X$ and trying to take the hemispheres from $S^{2n+1}$ down to $X$ as the choice of cover. My only complaint here is that I don't understand what the quotient ends up doing to this choice of cover very well.

Second, I tried using cellular homology directly. We know $\mathbb{C}P^n$ has a CW-structure given by $e^0\cup\dots\cup e^{2n}$ i.e. we glue a cell in each even dimension up to $2n$. The gluing map is the quotient map $S^{2k+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{k}$ at each step. Now for $X$, I would like to claim $X$ has a CW-complex structure (but this need not hold in general). In the dummy case of $n=1$, I know that $X=\mathbb{R}P^2$. But I cannot see it beyond this situation...

A hint would be appreciated as opposed to a full solution!

Comment: To make sure I understand, $f$ only negates the first coordinate, right?  Also, it seems to me that if $n=1$, $X=S^2$.  After the usual identification of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ with $S^2$, $f$ is a rotation by $\pi$ radians.  Viewing $S^2$ as the suspension of $S^1$, the quotient is the suspension of $S^1/{f}=S^1$, so is still $S^2$.  Or I made a stupid mistake...

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, $f$ negates only the first coordinate.
I thought that $\mathbb{C}P^1$ is identifiable with $S^2$ (not $\mathbb{C}P^2$).

I could be wrong since I assumed that $f$ was the antipodal map in this case... Does quotienting commute with suspension?

Comment: I meant $\mathbb{C}P^1$, sorry.  The map $f$ can't correspond to the antipidal map since it fixes the points $[1:0]$ and $[0:1]$.  A general quotienting won't commute with suspension  but in this case it seems a way to communicate the picture in my head.

Comment: I wrote a full answer before noticing your "hint would be preferred to a full solution"; I've now deleted it.  The way I did it was to first show that $X$ is homeomorphic to the mapping cone of the Hopf map $\mathbb{R}P^{2n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$, then used Mayer-Vietoris on the mapping cone, with $U$ being the "top" portion (which is the suspension of $\mathbb{R}P^{2n-1}$ and with $V$ being the "bottom" portion (which is the mapping cylinder of $\mathbb{R}P^{2n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$, so deformation retracts onto $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$...

Comment: If you'd rather see the (rather long) full solution, I'm happy to undelete.  I'm also curious what the ring structure ends up being on the cohomology, so I may continue to work on it just for fun....

Comment: @JasonDeVito I'm more than happy to see the full solution since it appears that the proof you sketched in the other comment is not precisely what I would have expected...

Comment: I've undeleted.  I was aiming for a proof with as little machinery as possible.  But if, e.g., you know the Gysin sequence or spectral sequences, the proof of the proposition can be significantly shortened.  Likewise, if you know the Thom isomorphism theorem, the whole arguement is just a few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is that

> $H_\ast(X)\cong \begin{cases}\mathbb{Z} & 0\leq \ast\leq 2n, \ast \text{ even}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Here's a proof.  We'll start by setting up notation.  I'm going to think of $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ as the mapping cone, $C(\pi)$ of the Hopf map $\pi:S^{2n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$.  That is $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is homeomorphic to $C(\pi):=S^{2n-1}\times [0,1]/\sim$ where $\sim$ identifies $S^{2n-1}\times \{0\}$ to a single point, and it identifies points in $S^{2n-1}\times \{1\}$ if they are in the same Hopf orbit.  If you think about it this is nothing but the usual cell stucture on $\mathbb{C}P^n$:  The subspace consisting of points in $S^{2n-1}\times [0,1)/\sim$ is a disk $D^{2n}$, which is being glued to $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1} = S^{2n-1}\times \{1\}/\sim$ via the Hopf map.

An explicit homeomorphism is given by $\phi:\mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow C(\pi)$ defined by $\phi([z_0:z_1:...:z_n]) = \left(\frac{|z_0|}{\sqrt{1-|z_0|}^2}\left(\frac{z_1}{z_0},...., \frac{z_n}{z_0}\right), 1-|z_0|\right)$.  Note that when $|z_0| = 1$, the first coodinate doesn't really make sense, but all such points get identified in the quotient.  Likewise, when $|z_0| = 0$, the first coordinate doesn't make sense, but it still does as  point in $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$.

What does $f$ look like in this description?  Well, away from the points with $|z_0| = 0,1$, it's just the antipodal map.  But at the single point where $|z_0| = 1$, it fixes that point, and it also fixes the $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ worth of points where $|z_0| = 0$.

Thus, we may describe $C(\pi)/f$ as $\mathbb{R}P^{2n-1}\times [0,1]/\sim$, where $\sim$ works the same way.

Said another way, $\mathbb{C}P^n/f$ is $C(\rho)$ where $\rho:\mathbb{R}P^{2n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ is real-projective Hopf map.

We are now ready to compute the topology, using Mayer-Vietoris.  Fix $\epsilon$ to be a tiny real number and let $U\subseteq C(\rho)$ with $U = \{([x,t]\in C(\rho): t\in [0, 1/2 + \epsilon)\}$ and also let $V = \{([x,t]\in C(\rho): t\in (1/2-\epsilon, 1]\}$.

The space $U$ is the open cone on $\mathbb{R}P^{2n-1}$, so clearly deformation retracts to a point.  The space $V$ is the mapping cylinder of $\rho$, so clearly deformation retracts to $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$.

The subspace $U\cap V$ deformation retracts to $\mathbb{R}P^{2n-1}\times \{1/2\}$.

The last bit of info we need is what the inclusion map $U\cap V\rightarrow V$ does on homology.  Of course, in dimension $0$, it's an isomorphism.  Otherwise, it's the trivial map:  $U\cap V$ only has homology in odd degrees while $V$ only has homology in even degrees.  We'll see later that we need a bit more: what the inclusion map does on homology with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.

**Proposition:**  Consider the inclusion map $i:U\cap V\rightarrow V$.  Then the induced map $$i_\ast:H_{2k}(U\cap V;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cong H_{2k}(V; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$$ is an isomorphism.

**Proof**:  Up to homotopy, the map $i$, followed by the deformation retract from $V$ to $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$, is nothing but $\rho$.  Thus, we are really interested in determining $\rho_\ast$.

To that end, consider $\mathbb{R}P^{2k}\subseteq \mathbb{R}P^{2n-1}\times \{1/2\}$, where we think of $\mathbb{R}P^{2n-1}$ as classes $\langle z_0:...:z_n\rangle\in S^{2n-1}/a$, where $a:S^{2n-1}\rightarrow S^{2n-1}$ is the antipodal map, and where we think of $\mathbb{R}P^{2k}$ as the subset set $\langle 0:..: t: z_{n-k+1}:...:z_n\rangle$ with $t$ real.  (So, given a point $(z_0,...,z_n)\in S^{2n+1}\subseteq \mathbb{C}P^{n+1}$, I'm using the notation $\langle z_0:...:z_n\rangle$ to denote its image in $\mathbb{R}P^{2n+1}$, and $[z_0:...:z_n]$ for the image in $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$.)

It is well known that $[\mathbb{R}P^{2k}]$ generates $H_{2k}(\mathbb{R}P^{2n-1};\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.  Thus, we must determine $\rho([\mathbb{R}P^{2k}]) = [\rho(\mathbb{R})P^{2k})]$.

Now, $\rho|_{\mathbb{R}P^{2k}}\mathbb{R}P^{2k}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ has image in $\mathbb{C}P^k\subseteq \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$, which has the same dimension as $\mathbb{R}P^{2k}$.  So we can just compute its mod $2$ degree in the usual sense.

If we consider a point $[\cos(\theta):\sin(\theta)z_{n-k+1}:...:\sin(\theta)z_n]$, then it's not too hard to verify that this gives a regular point whenever both trig functions are non-vanishing.  Such a point has preimage consisting of precisely one point in $\mathbb{R}P^{2k}$:  the point $\langle 0:...:t:\sin(\theta)z_{n-k+1}:...:\sin(\theta)z_n\rangle$ with $t = \pm \cos(\theta)$.  Thus, the mod $2$ degree of the map is $1$, establishing the proposition.  $\square$

Armed with all this info, we can apply Mayer-Vietoris.  Beginning with integer coefficients, all the map $H_k(U\cap V)\rightarrow H_k(U)\oplus H_k(V)$ are trivial (except when $k =0$, of course), so we obtain short exact sequences of the form $$0\rightarrow H_k(U)\oplus H_k(V)\rightarrow H_k(X)\rightarrow H_{k-1}(U\cap V)\rightarrow 0.$$

When $k$ is odd, $H_k(V) = H_{k-1}(U\cap V) = 0$, which implies $H_k(X) = 0$.

Wen $k = 2n$, we instead get $$0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow H_k(X)\rightarrow  \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0,$$ so $H_k(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

When $k< 2n$ is even, $H_k(V)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_{k-1}(U\cap V) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so we get an exact sequence of the form $$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow H_k(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0.$$

This tells us that $H_k(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ or $H_k(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, but it doesn't pin down which option occurs.

To answer this, we'll rerun Mayer-Vietories with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.  (I'll use $R$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ just to save on typing.)   It's still true that when $k$ is odd, that $H_k(U;R)\oplus H_k(V;R) = 0$.  Thus the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, beginning with $0 = H_{2k+1}(U;R)\oplus H_{2k+1}(V;R)$, breaks into longer sequences of the form $$ 0\rightarrow H_{2k+1}(X;R)\rightarrow H_{2k}(U\cap V;R)\rightarrow H_{2k}(V;R)\rightarrow H_{2k}(X;R)\rightarrow H_{2k-1}(U\cap V;R)\rightarrow 0 .$$

This is $$0\rightarrow H_{2k+1}(X;R)\rightarrow R\rightarrow R\rightarrow H_{2k}(X;R)\rightarrow R\rightarrow 0.$$

The map $R\rightarrow R$ is the one from the proposition, so we know it's an isomorphism.  Thus, we conclude $H_{2k+1}(X;R) = 0$ and $H_{2k}(X;R) \cong R$.

Since we already know that $H_{2k}(X;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}\oplus R$, universal coefficients now tells us that it must be the first option.

Comment: Okay, I think this proof is sufficient and correct on a first skim.
My next question is this: the homology of $X$ seems to indicate that the space $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{C}P^n$. Is this true or false? 

The reason I ask is that if it is true, maybe we can find a homotopy $X\simeq \mathbb{C}P^n$ for an alternative (and maybe easier) solution.

Comment: For $n=1$, they are homeomorphic, but for any larger $n$, the cohomology ring structures are different, so they aren't even homotopy equivalent.  One can basically copy the proof above using cohomology to see the induced map $H^\ast(X)\rightarrow H^\ast(V)$ is injective with image twice a generator.  Then using the fact that $V$ has the homotopy type of a complex projective space, it follows that, e.g., the square of a generator of $H^2(X)$ is twice a generator of $H^4(X)$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! In this case, I think another method of proof for computing the homology is to study the cell structure. Like if we can show that the quotient has a CW-complex structure that has 1 cell in each even dimension, then the homology is clear.